# Access GUI and method of engaged a lot of time

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, ms-access, .net-4.0

It's a Windows Form Application

And kind of code:

```
public bool Simulation(string param1, bool param2)
        {
            //code1
            do
            {
                bool success = reader.Launch();
                //code2
            } while (!success);
        }
```

`Launch()` method takes a long time but I have to wait in this place ("`code2`") at the same time having access to the GUI. Now `Launch()` is blocking this access.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand exactly what you need, but it sounds like you want to run your entire Simulation method on a separate thread from your UI thread.  If that is the case, you can just do something like this:

```
// From UI thread e.g. button click event handler
bool result; 

Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        result = Simulation(p1, p2);
    });
```

Note that result would be populated from a second thread... it's not clear from the question if you need to access result, or from which thread.  If you can clarify that, I can give more concrete guidance on how/where to check result.

Comment: 'success' is needed in Simulation() so if I start e.g. Launch in another thread it sould be available in main thread. In other words: 'success' is needed in while loop so it must wait to result of Launch additionaly. Is it more understandable? (Sorry for my english)

Comment: @Saint: I understand that you need `success` within Simulation, and that will work with the code I posted.  My question is whether/how you need the boolean returned from `Simulation`.